# R code running on taskscheduler but the database is not getting updated

Tags: r, windows-task-scheduler

I have scheduled some R code which is downloading a file from a link and updating a MY SQL database.

When I trigger the code manually, it functions fine.

However when I check the task scheduler-triggered runs, the log says the code is executing, but the the db is not updating.

I have tried multiple things but nothing is working.

Any ideas/suggestions on what i might be missing?

```
 library(RSelenium)
 library(seleniumPipes)
 library(rvest)
 library(httr)
 library(RCurl)
 library(XML)
 library(data.table)
 library(janitor)
 library(tidyr)
 library(splitstackshape)
 library(xtable)
```

## For link 1

```
 unlink("c:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\ticket_results.csv")
 browseURL("download link")
 Sys.sleep(10)
 Tickets1 <- read.csv("c:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\ticket_results.csv", 
 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F, check.names = F)
 Tickets1$`Case ID` <- paste0("0",Tickets1$`Case ID`)
 Tickets1 <- as.data.frame(Tickets1)
 Tickets <- Tickets1
 Sys.sleep(10)
```

## For link 2

```
 unlink("c:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\ticket_results.csv")
 browseURL("link download 2")
 Sys.sleep(10)
 Tickets1 <- read.csv("c:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\ticket_results.csv", 
 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F, check.names = F)
 Tickets1$`Case ID` <- paste0("0",Tickets1$`Case ID`)
 Tickets1 <- as.data.frame(Tickets1)
 Tickets <- rbind(Tickets,Tickets1)
 Sys.sleep(10)
```

#Update DB

```
 library(dbConnect)
 library(RMySQL)

 iConn <- RMySQL::dbConnect(
   RMySQL::MySQL(),
   host = 'xxxx',
   port = xxxx,
   dbname = 'xxxx',
   user = 'xxxx',
  password = 'xxxx'
 )
```

and finally updating

```
  RMYSQL::dbWriteTable(iConn, 'table_to_update', as.data.frame(Tickets),overwrite 
  =T row.names=F,
                 field.type=list(CaseID='varchar(20)', 
                                 Description='varchar(100)')
```

Comment: How are you executing your script? SSIS? RScript? Maybe there lies your problem.

Comment: I am running an R Script